# React native android text has extra bottom padding

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to align my two text components to the baseline of the first and I can't seem to get it working on android. I know that android deals with calculating the top and bottom spacing of the font and I tried using includeFontPadding: false, which works but only for the top. The bottom padding remains. Can anyone please help? Here's a snack showing my issue: https://snack.expo.io/S1ZAgflum

Edited: I modified the snack to remove the lineHeight and includeFontPadding properties to show the problem I'm having more clearly.

Below is a direct comparison from the snack and I've added a red line to show the difference in the number's height.

[image]

Comment: plz share some code

Comment: Have you gotten it to work in other contexts? I ask because the issue could be that the font itself has built in padding along the bottom. To confirm, you could try setting the padding to a negative number (if that works in general).

Comment: I tried adding paddinBottom: -20, but it does nothing and atm I'm using the default android font

Comment: I didn't see any difference between iOS and Android on the snack, and it looks like explicitly setting the line height is also causing problems as it aligns to the top of the height.

Comment: @MikeM I removed the lineHeight and includeFontPadding properties to show a better representation of the problem. I also included a picture of both android and iOD side by side and I added a line red line to show the difference in height

Comment: ok, can see it now.  One workaround might be to add `paddingBottom:Platform.OS==='ios'?0:15` to paragraph 1

Comment: @MikeM Yeah that would work. I'm surprised there's no way to remove that bottom padding on paragraph 2 though...

Answer (score 3):

I' don't know if is too late, but I solved this setting the height of the text element with the same value of the fontSize.